# P/Invoke - Marshaling delegate as function pointer + void*

Tags: c#, pinvoke

A fairly common idiom in C is for functions taking a polymorphic closure to represent this as two arguments, a function pointer and void pointer (which is passed as one of the arguments to the function pointer.

An example taken from the [GPGME](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) library:

```
typedef gpgme_error_t (*gpgme_passphrase_cb_t) (void *hook,
                                                const char *uid_hint,
                                                const char *passphrase_info,
                                                int prev_was_bad, 
                                                int fd);

void gpgme_set_passphrase_cb (gpgme_ctx_t ctx,
                              gpgme_passphrase_cb_t cb, 
                              void *hook_value);
```

Conceptually, the function pointer plus void pointer represent the same thing as a delegate in C# (a closure). Is there a nice, canonical way to marshal a delegate when making this sort of P/Invoke call?

Comment: Be careful, it is your job to keep the delegate object alive.  Store it in a static variable so it cannot be garbage-collected too early.  Only set the variable back to null when you are sure that the C code can no longer make the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a nice, canonical way to marshal a delegate when making this sort of P/Invoke call?

You don't need to use the `void*` parameter because a C# delegate is a closure. Pass `IntPtr.Zero` as the hook value. Your C# delegate still needs to accept the `void*` parameter but it can simply ignore it since it does not need it.

Comment: Thanks. It's been a little while since I've worked with .NET. I would guess that means that some sort of shim is held in global memory to adapt the delegate to a pure function pointer?

Comment: Correct. The marshalling framework generates code during marshalling that contains the closure information.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, however, I just wanted to append some C#9 information:

It is now possible to use function pointers in C# as follows (requires `unsafe` to be enabled):

```
static int add(int a, int b) => a + b;

delegate*<int, int, int> pointer = &add;
int result = add(40, 2);
```

Function pointers such as in the code snippet above are internally handled as `nint` (or `IntPtr`) and can be used in P/Invoke declarations:

```
[DllImport("my_library.dll")]
static extern int CallMyCallback(delegate*<int, int, int> callback, int arg1, int arg2);
```

An example C++ implementation of `my_library.dll` could be:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CallMyCallback(
    int (*callback)(int, int),
    int arg1,
    int arg2)
{
    return callback(arg1, arg2);
}
```

`CallMyCallback` could be used as follows (from C#):

```
static int multiply(int a, int b) => a * b;

int result = CallMyCallback(&multiply, -12, 7);
```

---

*Note:* This language feature cannot be used with lambda-expressions or non-static methods (instance methods require an implicit `this`-pointer to be passed).

---

The official documentation does not exist yet, but you can take a look at the C#9 GitHub issue/tracker: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/191

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pass delegate from C# to C function pointer. You should decorate this delegate with `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer]`attribute. This is how we wrapped a C method that takes function pointer:

The C method:

```
__declspec(dllexport) globle int EnvAddRouterEx(int (*queryFunction)(void*, char*))
```

The P\Invoke method:

```
[DllImport(clipsDllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern int EnvAddRouterEx(ClipsRouterQueryFunctionDelegate queryFunction);
```

The P\Invoke delegate:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int ClipsRouterQueryFunctionDelegate(IntPtr theEnv, string logicalName);
```